# Spring doesn't file properties files

Tags: java, spring, file-io, filenotfoundexception

I'm having troubles accessing properties files with Spring.
Here is my arborescence :

```
WEB-INF
   - application-Context.xml
   - properties
      -applicationPerperties.xml
      -csvHeader.properties
```

Here is my import in the application-context.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd"
    profile="dev, test, prod">

    <import resource="properties/applicationProperties.xml" />
</beans>
```

Here is the import in applicationProperties.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util      http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <util:properties id="csvDictionnaryProperties"  location="csvHeader.properties" />
</beans>
```

What I don't understand is the fact that Spring find applicationProperties.xml but doesn't find csvHeader.Properties. I tried moving this file to the root folder, adding classpath prefix and so, but I can't manage to make this work. I always get a `FileNotFoundException`.

Here is the stacktrace :

```
11:24:54,710 ERROR [ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'csvDictionnaryProperties': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/csvHeader.properties]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:608)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/csvHeader.properties]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:140)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getInputStream(EncodedResource.java:143)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:98)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:175)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.mergeProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:156)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean.createInstance(PropertiesFactoryBean.java:113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean.createProperties(PropertiesFactoryBean.java:98)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(PropertiesFactoryBean.java:69)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBe
```

As you can see, it seems that it searches csvHeader.properties in the / directory, but I can't understand why. I'm new to Spring, so I'm don't fully understand this all. Any ideas why this doesn't work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .properties file needs to be in the CLASSPATH.  Put it in WEB-INF/classes of your project and refer to it as classpath:csvHeader.properties.  Spring will find it then.

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks ! But I don't get why it didn't find the files. Is it stated by Spring that .properties file must be in the classpath ?

Comment: It looks for them as a resource in the classpath.  Yes, it's stated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following way.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:/WEB-INF/properties/applicationPerperties.xml" />
```

Or just start path with /WEB-INF/properties/

Answer (score 0):

Place the properties file within the root of your classpath then use the configuration provided below.

In Eclipse, everything within a `source folder` usually winds up on the classpath, so if you place the file at the root of a source directory, Spring should locate it.  In a Maven architecture, this source folder is ussually, `src/main/resources`.

```
<util:properties id="csvDictionnaryProperties" 
       location="classpath:csvHeader.properties" />
```